# Type mismatch. Value (x) does not match type number in column index 1

Tags: javascript, null, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

I have google visualization pie chart that I'm drawing like so:

```
OIT_location_pie_chart1.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
            // get the filtered results
            OIT_location_pie_chart.getDataTable(), [1], [{'column': 15, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}] //problem at 'type': 'number'
            ));
            OIT_location_pie_chart1.draw();
      });
```

There are some column values in the table that are empty after a certain date, so that data errors out if the user tries to show data after that specific date.

How do I check the data type for the rows that are erring out and account for them/ignore them?

Comment: are the empty values `null`? if so, that should be fine. the error states it found value `x`, which isn't a number. will you please share a sample of the data?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 2181.2345.3990.7761.6992.62185.2492.6246.3146.3123.1646.3192.6246.3146.3146.3169.4795.8947.9547.9547.9595.8931.6447.9595.947.9547.9535479.23579.9631.3431.3431.3486.0261.6961.6961.6962.67423.9562.6762.6762.6762.6762.6762.6762.6762.6762.6762.6762.6764.4764.4764.4764.4764.47139.2364.4764.4711286.6930.8521.16626.45126.9487.5629.19124.55153.02133.4544.4820.3517.6859.3175.9259.3150.42103.829.6627.4314.83137.1329.6615.25153.815.2530.5379.9730.515.2512230.5111.6330.545.3990.7745.3992.6292.6292.6246 does not match type number in column index 1

Comment: I put value (x) because the value is this huge list of numbers. I think it skips over the empty value and tries to grab all following values. How would I be able to verify that the empty values are null?

Comment: I know for sure that the error is caused by empty cell values because the piechart works correctly until a date with a corresponding null column is selected.

Comment: I just manually went in and filled in those columns throughout the spread sheet :/ not the best, but faster than how long it's been taking me to find a solution for this. Thanks for always wanting to help @WhiteHat

Comment: maybe not the best, but probably the simplest...